# Doesn't set cookies if domain is not localhost

Tags: go, go-gin

i have a problem when setting the cookies other than localhost in gin gonic

```
c.SetCookie("token", str, 60*60*24, "/", "localhost:3000", true, true) // WORKS

c.SetCookie("token", str, 60*60*24, "/", "192.162.1.12:3000", true, true) // DOESN'T WORK
```

my headers are like this

```
router.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
    AllowOrigins:     []string{"http://localhost:3000", "http://192.162.1.12:3000"},
    AllowMethods:     []string{"POST", "OPTIONS", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE"},
    AllowHeaders:     []string{"Accept", "Authorization", "Content-Type", "Content-Length", "X-CSRF-Token", "Token", "session", "Origin", "Host", "Connection", "Accept-Encoding", "Accept-Language", "X-Requested-With"},
    ExposeHeaders:    []string{"Content-Length"},
    AllowCredentials: true,
    // AllowOriginFunc: func(origin string) bool {
    //  return origin == "https://github.com"
    // },
    MaxAge: 24 * time.Hour,
}))
```

Im calling the api from my localhost "http://192.162.1.12:3000" react page.

I do get set-cookie token but is not set in cookies.
response:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:5001/client-users-login
Request method: POST
Status code: 200 OK
Remote address: [::1]:5001
Referrer origin directive: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://192.168.1.10:3000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length
Content Length: 407
Content Type: application/json; charset = utf-8
Date: Tuesday, January 24, 2023 14:35:44 GMT
Set-Cookie: token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJicmFuY2hBZGRyZXNzIjoiYXNkYXNkc2FkIiwiYnJhbmNoSWQiOjEsImJyYW5jaE5hbWUiOiJTdWN1cnNhbCAxIiwiYnJhbmNoUGhvbmUiOiIyMzIzMjMyMyIsImNsaWVudElkIjoxLCJjbGllbnROYW1lIjoidGVzdCIsImNvbXBhbnlJZCI6MSwiZXhwIjoxNjc0NjU3MzQ0LCJnZXRTdGFydGVkIjpmYWxzZSwicm9sZUlkIjoxLCJzdGF0ZUlkIjoxLCJ1c2VyIjoidGVzdEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJ1c2VySWQiOiIwIn0.QhQCWMhmqcwBNVu_4EEoHdGZj0f3nUKRVCqtnUYZ8q4; path=/; Domain=192.168.1.10; Max-Age=86400; Http only; Insurance; SameSite=None
Vary: Origin
Accept: */*
Accept encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es,es-ES;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
Connection: keep alive
Content Length: 50
Content Type: application/json
Host: localhost:5001
Source: http://192.168.1.10:3000
Reference: http://192.168.1.10:3000/
sec-ch-ua: "Not_A Brand";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: between sites
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/109.0.1518.61
```

Comment: What is the exact raw http response (as-is, unmodified)? Aren't you missing `http://` in the second origin?

Comment: @zerkms Hi, no.

Comment: And what about the first question from my comment?

Comment: Cookie Domains have no port. You try to do something that violates how cookies work.

Comment: @Volker Hello i tried without ports and dosnt works

Comment: @zerkms i edited the question check the response.

Comment: Your domain is localhost (see "Request URL: http://localhost:5001/client-users-login " and "Host: localhost:5001") but you try to set cookies for 192.168.1.10. How do you expect this to work? There is no magic going on to determine that somehow localhost and 192.168.1.10 are the same machine.